# Need to overlay image along line chart HTML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so I am working on a personal project right now and I need to overlay a series of different images along a line for a reporting application I am working on.

I am new to web development, or visual display of data in general to be honest, but this is an oddly specific question that I haven't been able to track down the answer to.

I have a line defined by a series of survey points. Along this line I need to draw a visual representation of a geologic rock type. That visual representation can change at different intervals than the line segments which is why I can't simply define the line style itself as the image in question.

I am not looking for specific instructions, I am looking for a general direction to start investigating.

I've attached a picture of what I want the output to look like.

[image: sample image]

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you are already using? I would also suggest looking into a chart plugin such as chart.js for charts and graphs

Comment: I have no code at all yet. Looking for places to start. Chart.js is a great option for some of the things I need to do, but I'm not sure of how to display the lithologies (the yellow area with the dots in it) along the chart.